# Copied Multi-site WordPress Application to New Host, Error connecting to DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

I have copied a WordPress application to a new hosting environment. The application has subdomains enabled, however our new hosting environment does not support this. I have updated `.htaccess` as well as `wp-config.php` to reflect the new URL and new database. I am unable to navigate through the site whatsoever. Going to wp-admin leads me to the classic error message:

> Error establishing a database connection
>       If your site does not display, please contact the owner of this network. If you are the owner of this network please check that MySQL is running properly and all tables are error free.
>
> Could not find site example.com. Searched for table wp_blogs in database wp. Is that right?
>
> What do I do now? Read the bug report page. Some of the guidelines there may help you figure out what went wrong. If you’re still stuck with this message, then check that your database contains the following tables:

```
wp_users
wp_usermeta
wp_blogs
wp_signups
wp_site
wp_sitemeta
wp_registration_log
wp_blog_versions
```

I imagine this has something to do with the URL mappings in the database. Keep in mind, we are trying to switch from subdomains to subdirectories. What steps must I take to correct this in addition to switching over from subdomains?

Comment: This has nothing to do with URL mappings. The SQL credentials (username, password, hostname) in wp-config.php are just wrong.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider why does everyone always assume the credentials are wrong?! I have a similar issue right now and I did a PHP function to check if I can connect to the same database with the same credentials and guess what - I CAN, so nothing wrong with the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to switch from subdomain to subdirectory.

This forum topic should have most of the details needed: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/reverting-from-subdomains-to-subdirectories-in-multistie

That said when migrating to a new host with multisite and getting the DB connectivity errors, what usually is the cause is the mismatch in the wp_blogs & wp_sites tables.

If you can manually edit those tables and correct at least your primary domain you should be able to get back in and correct the rest via the network admin.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "the wp_site table", not "wp_sites tables"? I'm having the same issue as OP and even though the wp_blogs and wp_site table aren't mismatched, it's still not working. Hence why I'm here. Even did a search in the DB for the old URL and changing those that have an impact (i.e. links within posts etc I ignore for now,) I still can't get in to wp-admin, or view the page.